# Set the max size of Particular.ServiceControl queue in azure

Tags: azure, nservicebus, max-size

ServiceControl automatically creates the Particular.ServiceControl queue in Azure for me when it starts up, but it sets the max size to 1GB and Message Time to Live as 1067519.911673 days. Is there a way I can configure ServiceControl to set the max queue size and time to live to another value?

Answer (score -1):

Will [this documentation](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/using-azure-servicebus-as-transport-in-nservicebus#configuring-in-detail) help answer your question?